# how to take the same random key in a py dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I want take random key in this dict :

```
{'F' : 'FF', 'B' : 'F[[-B][+B]]F[+FB]-B','B': 'F[-B]F[-FB]+B',}
```

I have same key this is normal and if the key is 'B' I want one of the two associated values to be returned to me.
i.e. if the key is 'B' the result must be`'F[[-B][+B]]F[+FB]-B'`or`'F[-B]F[-FB]+B'`randomly
and i didn't see how to make that.

Comment: Note that you have `'B'` key twice. The first value for that key will be lost and you can never return it. Consider to make this dict of lists.

Comment: Yes I know then how I do so that the two values and a 50% chance of being returned

Comment: The dictionary is invalid to begin with. Instead, you probably want to have the key be `B`, and the values be a list `['F[[-B][+B]]F[+FB]-B', 'F[-B]F[-FB]+B']`. To randomly sample a value, query into the key and select one of the values in the list.

Comment: @JakeTae, actually the dict literal is valid and will not raise error, only that last seen wins and the first value for key B will be lost

Comment: @buran, you're right, it would initialize fine. I meant to say that it's invalid from a user point of view (it's not what was intended). Thanks for pointing it out though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A dictionary can only have unique keys.

You could use a dictionary of lists and get a random choice using `random.choice`:

```
d = {'F' : ['FF'], 'B': ['F[[-B][+B]]F[+FB]-B', 'F[-B]F[-FB]+B']}

import random
random.choice(d['B'])
```

output: `'F[[-B][+B]]F[+FB]-B'` or `'F[-B]F[-FB]+B'` (50% chance each)

Answer (score 0):

Using random.choice is not a bad idea at all. I wrote up a little class that uses a dictionary of lists to achieve a similar result.

```
import random

class randomizer:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = {}
    def add(self,k,v):
        try:
            self.data[k].append(v)
        except:
            self.data[k] = [v]
    def get(self,k):
        i = int(random.random()*len(self.data[k]))
        # ^ this is where you could use random.choice
        return(self.data[k][i])

d = randomizer()
d.add("a",1)
d.add("a",2)
d.add("a",3)
d.add("b",4)
d.add("b",5)
for k in range(0,5):
    print(d.get("a"))
for k in range(0,5):
    print(d.get("b"))
```